# Clash between mhchem and breqn. Any way to dodge or fix?

Tags: incompatibility, breqn, mhchem

The use of `breqn` causes the subscript numbers in chemical expressions, formatted by `mhchem`, to be exlargened and perhaps moved slightly making it look ugly.

Is there a way to avoid this or should I stop using `breqn`?

Many thanks

MWE - comment out `breqn` to see the diference

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 

\begin{document}
\ce{H2SO4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please present a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I think it is something to do with `mhchem` using the dmath environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\xxmathchoice\mathchoice
\usepackage{breqn}
\let\yymathchoice\mathchoice

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 

\begin{document}
\let\mathchoice\xxmathchoice
\ce{H2SO4}
 ...
\let\mathchoice\yymathchoice
\begin{dmath}...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this break `breqn`?

Comment: well not if you put it back again, I suppose I should show that

Comment: So before each time you plan to use the `dmath` environment  you also add your \let\mathchoice\... before and after? I'll have a go. :)

Comment: @Darling Or you patch the `\ce` macro itself: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\ce[1]{\let\mathchoice\xxmathchoice\mhchem@ce@xiii{\mhchem@ce@viii#1 \mhchem@END\mhchem@ENDEND}\let\mathchoice\yymathchoice}\makeatother` (or use `etoolbox`’s `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd`)