# Conflict between breqn and \dashint

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, breqn

If I use the following code to get an average integral

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\def\dashint{\,\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
            \stackinset{c}{.2\LMpt}{c}{.5\LMpt}{\SavedStyle-}{\SavedStyle\phantom{\int}}}%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\int\,$}\kern-\wd0}\int}

\begin{document}

    $\dashint f(t)\,dt$

\end{document}
```

I get this nice result:

[image]

However, if I also load the package *breqn* (no matter where I put the line \usepackage{breqn} in the preamble) it does not work anymore, i.e. I get this strange result:

[image]

Is anybody able to figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that `breqn` has a bug which breaks `\mathchoice`.

Here is the MWE that shows it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$\mathchoice{Displaystyle}{Textstyle}{Scriptstyle}{scriptscriptstyle}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\mathchoice` macro is a fundamental TeX command for distinguishing the style of math mode.  The above case should yield a "Textstyle" and does so, if `breqn` is not loaded.  It indicates that the code is in `\textstyle` math mode. However, with breqn loaded, it gives a "Displaystyle" as its output.

The `scalerel` package cannot function without knowing the actual math style that one resides in, as it uses `\mathchoice` to decode its `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax.

In the case of the OP's macro, the problem is that, with `breqn` loaded, the stack inside the `dashint` macro is setting the `\int` in display style, even if `\dashint` is invoked in text style, as in the OP's example.

---

While I initially showed a manual workaround, the OP reminds me (citing this question: [Clash between mhchem and breqn. Any way to dodge or fix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/clash-between-mhchem-and-breqn-any-way-to-dodge-or-fix)) that one can save the old definition of `\mathchoice` before loading `breqn` and then temporarily restore it for the use of `\dashint`.  In that way, the `scalerel` macros `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` will behave properly.

Here would be that code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\let\oldmathchoice\mathchoice
\usepackage{breqn}
\let\newmathchoice\mathchoice

\def\dashint{\let\mathchoice\oldmathchoice\,\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
            \stackinset{c}{.2\LMpt}{c}{.5\LMpt}{\SavedStyle-}{%
            \SavedStyle\phantom{\int}}}%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\int\,$}\kern-\wd0}\int%
        \let\mathchoice\newmathchoice}

\begin{document}
\centering
    $\dashint_a^b f(t)\,dt$

    \[\dashint_a^b f(t)\,dt\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is illuminating! I think another good workaround could be to save the original version of \mathchoice and temporarily restore it inside the definition of \dashint, as is done in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/clash-between-mhchem-and-breqn-any-way-to-dodge-or-fix (I tested it and it works!)

Comment: @Mizar Thanks.  I will edit my answer to reflect it.